# How to map a specific physical address range of linux kernel, of size less than one page size(4Kb) to user space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am working on a solution similar to user-space input/output drivers(Linux kernel UIO).

**[Linux kernel UIO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/uio-howto.html)**

I intend to map a specific physical address range(**starting at specific physical address**) from kernel space to user-space of size 0x100, which is less than one page size(4 Kb). I tried to solve this via kernel UIO framework but it maps(via **mmap** file operation of file */dev/uio*) minimum for one page. I want a solution so that I can map exact specific 0x100 physical memory to user-space. If the user-space tries to access beyond that 0x100 range, it should not be allowed. So far the solution I came across deal in page level mappings.

Comment: So mmaping /dev/ui works, you just want to limit it to 0x100 bytes?

Comment: It's impossible from architectural point of view. You may try to limit access to it, but it will be tricky and error prone hack.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but does brk syscall not do something  similar, i.e. providing limited access as asked by malloc function? Except that it doesn't map to specific physical memory.

Comment: No, `brk()` operates with pages beneath since it's a property of the OS and architecture. You may set a simple experiment to limit memory to something less than a page size and try to access the address in between, You won't get a page fault.